# JSONException while trying to convert data into a string

Tags: android, json

So there is a PHP file where I'm sending an array to my android device. After my device receives the data, it converts it to a string and after that I'm trying to get the assoc array index that was made with PHP. Here is a sample of the PHP code from before:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($query)){
    $output = array('message' => 'Group added to your database', 'succes' => 'true');

}else{
    $output = array('message' => 'Wrong username/password combination', 'succes' => 'false');
}

print(json_encode($output));
```

and here is how the code in my Android project looks like:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        dialog.dismiss();

        try{
            jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json_data=null;

            for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++){

                json_data               = jArray.getJSONObject(i);     

                String getMessage = json_data.getString("message");
                showToast(getMessage);
            }
        }
        catch(JSONException je){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error (JSONException): "+je.toString());
            showToast(result);
        } 
        catch (ParseException pe) {
            pe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Error log:

```
01-08 16:35:55.896: E/log_tag(647): Error (JSONException): org.json.JSONException: Value {"message":"Group added to your database","success":"true"} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
01-08 16:35:56.186: W/TextLayoutCache(647): computeValuesWithHarfbuzz -- need to force to single run
```

Comment: What details are given in the Json exception? Also succes is spelt 'success'.

Comment: Error (JSONException): org.json.JSONException: Value {"message":"Group added to your database","success":"true"} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create JSONArray from string that represents JSONObject, you should do:

```
try{
    JSONObject json_data=JSONObject(result);
    String getMessage = json_data.getString("message");
    showToast(getMessage);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I saw that too, but didn't quite know how to solve the problem. Thanx :)